# Using Apportable to make an app for the Play Store

Tags: android, ios, apportable

It seems like I am so close to getting my app to work with Apportable, but I must be missing something. I can get it to compile and load on my Android device, but I can't figure out how to get a version that I can upload to the Play Store.

I am following the instructions at http://docs.apportable.com/publishing.

I have generated a key using this command:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore release.keystore -alias mykey -keyalg RSA \
        -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

And then I do these commands:

```
BUILD=release
ANDROID_KEYSTORE=release.keystore
ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PASS=mypassword
apportable build
```

Then this is the output I am seeing:

```
Warning: Unable to find a file to match the following requested asset: /Users/xxx.xxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/../../../../../var/folders/k6/622y1j591td761hnpbwz9fzr8rr8br/T/tmpdw18sb/TARGET_BUILD_DIR/libObjectiveChipmunk.a
Warning: Module com.rrTenz.Tens/Tens: lib /Users/xxx.xxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/Tens/z does not exist
Warning: Module com.rrTenz.Tens/Tens: lib /Users/xxx.xxxxx/xxxxxx/app apple/Tens/sqlite3 does not exist
Warning: Module com.rrTenz.Tens/Tens: lib /Users/xxx.xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/Tens/ObjectiveChipmunk does not exist
[1/11] Writing Build/android-armeabi-debug/Tens/AndroidManifest.xml
[2/11] Zipping Build/android-armeabi-debug/Tens/Tens-debug.apk:/assets/Info.plist
[3/11] Creating Build/android-armeabi-debug/Tens/Tens-resources.apk and R.java files
[4/4] Building Build/android-armeabi-debug/Tens/Tens-debug.apk
```

Can somebody tell me what I am missing?

This is what I see after changing the package name and removing the space from the directory name:

```
 apportable build
Warning: Unable to find a file to match the following requested asset: /Users/ryan.tensmeyer/Dropbox/app_apple/Tens/../../../../../var/folders/k6/622y1j591td761hnpbwz9fzr8rr8br/T/tmpTQQuSR/TARGET_BUILD_DIR/libObjectiveChipmunk.a
Warning: Module com.rrtenz.Tens/Tens: lib /Users/ryan.tensmeyer/Dropbox/app_apple/Tens/z does not exist
Warning: Module com.rrtenz.Tens/Tens: lib /Users/ryan.tensmeyer/Dropbox/app_apple/Tens/sqlite3 does not exist
Warning: Module com.rrtenz.Tens/Tens: lib /Users/ryan.tensmeyer/Dropbox/app_apple/Tens/ObjectiveChipmunk does not exist
ninja: error: expected depfile '/Users/ryan.tensmeyer/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/com.rrtenz.Tens/Tens/Users/ryan.tensmeyer/Downloads/iAdHelper/iAdHelper.m.o.d' to mention '/Users/ryan.tensmeyer/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/com.rrtenz.Tens/Tens/Users/ryan.tensmeyer/Downloads/iAdHelper/iAdHelper.m.o', got '/Users/ryan.tensmeyer/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/com.rrTenz.Tens/Tens/Users/ryan.tensmeyer/Downloads/iAdHelper/iAdHelper.m.o'
Error: command failed: /Users/ryan.tensmeyer/.apportable/SDK/toolchain/macosx/ninja/ninja --no-strip-ansi-escapes -j 16 /Users/ryan.tensmeyer/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/Tens/Tens-debug.apk
```

This is my current output after doing an `apportable clean`:

```
apportable build

Warning: Unable to find a file to match the following requested asset: /Users/ryan.tensmeyer/Dropbox/appApple/TensApportable/../../../../../var/folders/k6/622y1j591td761hnpbwz9fzr8rr8br/T/tmpYWZNxo/TARGET_BUILD_DIR/libObjectiveChipmunk.a
Warning: Module com.rrtenz.Tens/Tens: lib /Users/ryan.tensmeyer/Dropbox/appApple/TensApportable/z does not exist
Warning: Module com.rrtenz.Tens/Tens: lib /Users/ryan.tensmeyer/Dropbox/appApple/TensApportable/sqlite3 does not exist
Warning: Module com.rrtenz.Tens/Tens: lib /Users/ryan.tensmeyer/Dropbox/appApple/TensApportable/ObjectiveChipmunk does not exist
[1/10] Writing Build/android-armeabi-debug/Tens/AndroidManifest.xml
[2/10] Creating Build/android-armeabi-debug/Tens/Tens-resources.apk and R.java files
[3/3] Building Build/android-armeabi-debug/Tens/Tens-debug.apk
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work by copying these commands into a text editor on a single line and modifying it with my keystore and password. So apparently it didn't like having it on 2 separate lines....I guess.

```
BUILD=release ANDROID_KEYSTORE=release.keystore \
        ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PASS=mypassword apportable build
```

Answer (score 1):

Your package name `com.rrTenz.Tens` is incorrect. The first capital `T` in `rrTenz` needs to be lower case, the second `T` is fine -- that one can remain capitalized.

Only the first two members of a package name need to be lowercase.

Comment: I changed the package name to com.rrtenz.Tens in Xcode and I have updated my question to show my new output. It's still showing the capital 'T' so I must have missed something.

Comment: You'll need to update your library paths with the new package name as well. Xcode? I don't use Xcode, so I can't help you there.

Comment: I changed the 'T' to 't' but I am still having problems. I updated the output in my question.

Answer (score 1):

The core issue is likely the space in the path - `/Users/ryan.tensmeyer/Dropbox/app apple`.

Try moving the app to a folder without a space.

Comment: I am still having problems after removing the space from the directory name. I updated the output in my question.

Comment: May need to apportable clean

Comment: I did an apportable clean and I can now get apportable load to work again. But I am still getting the same output as before (see my edited question).